# Save several entries in the same txt file (Windows Service Control)

Tags: batch-file, service, cmd

I am trying to create a bat script that will check the status of different services (using Service Control) on different machines and output it to a text file.
For instance:

```
sc (machine name) query eventlog > serviceStatus.txt
sc (machine name) query Wecsvc > serviceStatus.txt
```

Can anyone suggest how I can output the status of different windows services to the same text file?
I tried separating the queries with a comma, but it doesn't seem to be the right syntax..

Another thing I wondered about:
When I run the above code it outputs:

```
SERVICE_NAME: eventlog 
    TYPE               : 20  WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS  
    STATE              : 4  RUNNING 
                            (STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, ACCEPTS_SHUTDOWN)
    WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
    SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
    CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
    WAIT_HINT          : 0x0
```

I see that "State" is 4 when running. What is the "code" for it when it is stopped?

Comment: `>>` instead of `>` will append to an existing file.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of that :-) But I want the file to be overwritten each time I run the bat script, I suppose using >> will just keep populating the same file then?

Comment: So use `>` on the first one and `>>` on the rest? Or delete the file at the beginning of the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either delete any existing file at start and use append mode `>>`

```
del serviceStatus.txt 2>nul
sc machineName query eventlog >> serviceStatus.txt
sc machineName query Wecsvc >> serviceStatus.txt
```

Or use overwrite mode `>` for the first command and append mode for subsequent commands

```
sc machineName query eventlog > serviceStatus.txt
sc machineName query Wecsvc >> serviceStatus.txt
```

Or enclose all commands in parentheses and redirect only once using overwrite mode

```
>serviceStatus.txt (
  sc machineName query eventlog
  sc machineName query Wecsvc
)
```

Or if parentheses complicate things, then put all your output generating commands in a subroutine and CALL with redirection

```
call :sc >serviceStatus.txt
exit /b

:sc
sc machineName query eventlog
sc machineName query Wecsvc
exit /b
```

Note that the last two option are the most efficient. Probably not an issue in your case, but if in a long tight loop, then redirecting only once for the entire loop as opposed to many times within the loop can make a big difference in performance.

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
wmic /node:@"c:\computerlist.txt" /failfast:on Service where "name='eventlog' or name='wscsvc'" get name, pathname, state, status /format:list
```

This queries a list of servers specified in `c:\computerlist.txt`. The format is as below

```
127.0.0.1
MyServerA
MyServerB
192.168.0.1
```

To generate a list of turned on computers type the following

```
for /f "skip=3 delims=\" %A in ('net view ^| findstr /v /C:"The command completed successfully"') do Echo %A > C:\ComputerList.txt
```

The `Win32_Service` class is documented here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394418(v=vs.85).aspx. Although `wmic` has full help built in. `wmic /?`, `wmic service get /?`, and `wmic service call /?`.

Type `wmic /format /?` for a list of formats

This is `/format:list`

```
Name=EventLog
PathName=C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe -k LocalServiceNetworkRestricted
State=Running
Status=OK


Name=wscsvc
PathName=C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe -k LocalServiceNetworkRestricted
State=Running
Status=OK
```

This is `/format:csv`

```
Node,Name,PathName,State,Status
127.0.0.1,EventLog,C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe -k LocalServiceNetworkRestricted,Running,OK
127.0.0.1,wscsvc,C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe -k LocalServiceNetworkRestricted,Running,OK
```

There is also HTML output options. Try `hform`.